# Change the names property on query of two related models SEQUELIZE

Tags: sequelize.js

I have the two following models in Sequileze: User and Image.The User has an Image. I am doing a query as following:

```
User.findOne({
  include: [
    { model: Image,attributes: ["name"],required: true},
  ],
  raw: true,
}).then((user){
}
```

This query is returning me in the response of user a property as follows:

```
"image.name": "ImageName"
```

I want to change the "image.name" to "ImageName" and I tried this:

```
{ model: Image,attributes: [["name",""]],required: true}
```

But I still not getting what I want because it returns me this:

```
"image.": "ImageName"
```

I cannot delete the "image." on the names of the property.

Comment: can you please post the expected object and the received object (returned by the current query). Also I noticed that you are using `raw: true`, is this intentional?

Comment: Thank you anyway for your time, with the answer below it works !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because of `raw: true,` just remove that line and you are all good to go ,

I think you have used raw:true to get plain object from query and not extra params with that , you can that in this by using `toJSON()` property ,

```
User.findOne({
  include: [
    { model: Image,attributes: ["name"],required: true},
  ]
}).then((user){
  user = user.toJSON(); // here , this way
}
```